# AsynchronousFileChannel.open hangs when opening a FIFO (named pipe) for read

Tags: java, nio, named-pipes

On Linux, I have a named pipe created in the shell using `mkfifo /tmp/test`.

I would like to use it for async reads, so as a first step I am opening it using  `AsynchronousFileChannel`:

```
java.nio.channels.AsynchronousFileChannel.open(
    java.nio.file.Paths.get("/tmp/test"),
    java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption.READ)
)
```

However the call hangs:

```
"main" #1 prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=1830.11ms elapsed=686.74s tid=0x00007f444c016800 nid=0x6ae8 runnable  [0x00007f44527c2000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixNativeDispatcher.open0(java.base@11.0.7/Native Method)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixNativeDispatcher.open(java.base@11.0.7/UnixNativeDispatcher.java:71)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixChannelFactory.open(java.base@11.0.7/UnixChannelFactory.java:267)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixChannelFactory.newAsynchronousFileChannel(java.base@11.0.7/UnixChannelFactory.java:180)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newAsynchronousFileChannel(java.base@11.0.7/UnixFileSystemProvider.java:199)
    at java.nio.channels.AsynchronousFileChannel.open(java.base@11.0.7/AsynchronousFileChannel.java:253)
    at java.nio.channels.AsynchronousFileChannel.open(java.base@11.0.7/AsynchronousFileChannel.java:311)
```

Is it possible in Java to open a named pipe for async reads or writes?

Answer (score 3):

`man open` says:

```
   FIFOs
       Opening  the read or write end of a FIFO blocks until the other end is also opened (by an‐
       other process or thread).  See fifo(7) for further details.
```

Therefore, the Java call behaves as expected when opening a named pipe when there's nothing else connected to the other end. It looks like there is no way to pass `O_NONBLOCK` to get the desired behavior of a non-blocking `open`.

Comment: Also, please don't use `AsynchronousFileChannel` on FIFOs - you can workaround the open blocking by pushing the task to the system executor service that will wait on the open for you, but the problem is that `AsynchronousFileChannel` read and write operations require seeking to a specific position to read or write - which is not allowed for pipes and you'd just get exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

The read on a fifo will always block until there's something to read. I suspect this also applies when opening an async channel. Did you try writing to the fifo ?

Comment: Your question helped me see that if there's a writer connected to the pipe, `open` indeed returns a Channel. Similarly if I open for `StandardOpenOption.WRITE` it would exit only when there's a reader connected. The original question still stands: is it possible to open a file async (not requiring a connected party)?

Comment: @thesamet No, because you can't get the underlying FD out of blocking mode until you acquire it, and it is acquired from `open()`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Not accepting this answer due to "block until there's something to read" being incorrect. The correct condition is that it is blocked until the other end is also connected.